# CPArrayController not updating when new objects are added

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

**Problem**
Cappuccino app initially loads successfully. After an ajax call is made and an array is populated with JSON Objects, the Array Controller doesn't recognize it and populate the data.

**Setup**
Using the latest build from capp and xcc. I have an application where all of the IB elements are tied to an NSArrayController. It's bound to my AppController's CPMutableArray. I Import a controller class that fires off and handles the AJAX call. I have confirmed when it has finished that my CPMutableArray is populated with data.

This is just done with a simple "addObjectsFromArray"

So am I supposed to notify the ArrayController to reload or follow a procedure where it automatically picks up the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully update the page once I did the following

- <strike>Made my CPMutableArray into a CPArrayController. Since I am only adding and removing objects it hasn't beexn a change elsewhere in the code.</strike>
- Used KVO to add and remove objects: [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"persons"] addObject:me];

My biggest problem was relying on ./bootstrap.sh. It doesn't install and configure everything. Cloned the github /cappuccino/cappuccino and ran Jake Install. Now xcode is picking up my outlets and ibactions!